# What if I don't end a javascript function with a semicolon?

Tags: javascript, semicolon-inference

I'm working on javascript about a week, and I noticed that Visual Studio don't flag you a function if you don't end it with a semicolon:

```
function secondalert(){
alert ("Hi")
}

secondalert();
```

So as you can see i don't end the function with any semicolon, but Visual Studio, like any other text editor, don't flag it.

Is it wrong to don't end a function? And if semicolon is necessary, is it better if I put it after the curly brace?

Comment: Nope it's pretty the same thing, with a semicolon the code is more readable

Comment: when you are minify the javascript code it may create a problem. if you are not minifying it wont create any issue

Comment: It is actually not customary to end a function declaration with a semicolon. You won't find much code that does that.

Comment: Ok thanks you both.